# Perl Reading from Thread::Queue with timeout

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am working in a boss worker crew multithreaded scenario with Thread::Queue in Perl.
The boss enqueues tasks and the workers dequeue from the queue.
I need to achieve that the worker crew sends downstream ping messages in case the boss does not send a task via the queue for x seconds.
Unfortunately there seems to be no dequeue method with a timeout.
Have I missed something or would you recommend a different approach/different data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the functionality yourself, knowing that a `Thread::Queue` object is a blessed reference to a shared array (which I believe is the implementation from 5.8 through 5.16):

```
package Thread::Queue::TimedDequeue;

use parent 'Thread::Queue';
use threads::shared qw(lock cond_timedwait);

sub timed_dequeue {
  my ($q, $patience) = @_; # XXX revert to $q->dequeue() if $patience is negative?
                           #     $q->dequeue_nb() if $patience is zero?

  my $timelimit = time() + $patience;
  lock(@$q);
  until (@$q) {
    last if !cond_timedwait(@$q, $timelimit);
  }
  return shift if @$q; # We got an element

  # else we timed out.
}

1;
```

Then you'd do something like:

```
# main.pl
use threads;
use strict; use warnings;

use Thread::Queue::TimedDequeue;

use constant WORKER_PATIENCE => 10; # 10 seconds

my $queue = Thread::Queue::TimedDequeue->new();
...
sub worker {
  my $item = $queue->dequeue(WORKER_PATIENCE);
  timedout() unless $item;
  ...
}
```

Note that the above approach assumes you do *not* enqueue `undef` or an otherwise false value.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for. Maybe you can add this to the CPAN package?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach/structure, you just need to add some timeout control over your "Thread::Queue". That is either:

- create some "yield" based loop to check your queue from the child side while using a time reference to detect timeout.
- use the "Thread::Queue::Duplex" or "Thread::Queue::Multiplex" modules which might be a bit overill but do implement timeout controls.